# How to change "add to cart" in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I wanna use `<ul> <li>` instead of `<select> <option>` 
I enter this code in function.php but doesn't work:

```
function wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args = array() ) {
.
.
.
    $html  = '<div class="tt-wrapper"><div class="tt-title-options">اندازه:</div><ul id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="tt-options-swatch options-large ' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms(
                $product->get_id(),
                $attribute,
                array(
                    'fields' => 'all',
                )
            );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                    $html .= '<li><a href="#" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name, $term, $attribute, $product ) ) . '</a></li>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                $html    .= '<li><a href="#" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option, null, $attribute, $product ) ) . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul></div></div>';

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', $html, $args ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
}
```

How can I change woocommerce HTML codes to my own HTML codes? 
<strike>this is more detail for post this question</strike>

Answer (score 1):

To override the default themes of WooCommerce you better have a "woocommerce" sub-directory on your theme folder.
for example:
/wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/
There you can specify exactly which of the themes you want to change.
Learn more about it [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Also, you can hook to actions and filters. In the example you sent, you can hook to this filter: woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html to change it's final output.
Learn more about it [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/filter/) and [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/inside-wordpress-actions-filters/).